# Print Preview with Flex application?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

- Is there a way to add a visualise and manipulate the way the things goin to be printed from flex application before the printing them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya it can be done, It also depends on the type of document to be printed. If your application is document based then u can refer the following [Print Preview](http://blogs.soph-ware.com/posted-content/files/flex_printing_test/). 
Though it look like the pdf preview.

If your application is image shape added on stage then no other way.
you need to create the popup and add the followings, since you cannot clone that kind objects.

```
                     ~~~~~~~~~Happy Coding~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: this looks very promising. thank you very much. i am playing with it now :)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 3):

I have built a full functional PDF and Print Preview for Flex DataGrid and AdvancedDataGrid. It has also got some helpful tools that you can use before printing.
check it out http://blog.kreatx.com/2011/11/11/flex-printing-print-preview-pdf-generation/